# Stop logged in user seeing the log in page?

Tags: php, login-control

I'm very new to php and mysql. I have found a great tutorial to create a registration and log in section on a site. I'm managing to deconstruct it pretty well and make minor changes.
However...

If a user logs in I am able to allow accesss to pages using -

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

If a user is logged in and they revisit the 'log in' page again I don't want them to be able to see it but it redirect them to a page within the 'members area'. How can i do this?

Comment: If they save a username in their session redirect them away from the page. It's really that simple.

Comment: Be sure you die; or exit; after you perform the header call. That way the rest of your script does process!

Comment: Are you able to give an example of how I would redirect please? The log in page is on index.php but i want them to go to loggedin.php. I appreciate you say it is easy but I can't get it to work after several failed attempts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to load the same page in the URL, for example, http://domain.com/ , but you want it to be different for logged in people vs logged out people. You could do this.

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    require_once("pathToLoggedOutFile.php");
} else {
    require_once("PathToLoggedInFile.php");
}
die;
```

Now, the same can be done if you want to redirect them to another page when they are logged in, you could do this by using headers, for example.

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: /pathtologgedinpage.php");
    die;
}
```

Comment: Where would I place this code? The log in page is on index.php and I want to redirect to loggedin.php.

Comment: At the top of your file. Question though: Do you want the user to be on the same url when they log in? As in, Do you want it like facebook where when you go to facebook.com and if you are logged in, you see your homepage, not the login page? Or do you want to manually redirect them to /loggedin.php ?

Comment: @user1325308 you would want something like this to be processed when the user loads the page.

Comment: Notice I edited the post above to explain the differences and fix a minor problem. I had the paths reversed :P.

Comment: @TJohnW This will enforce a logout file when the session is not active, what the OP wants is to be able to restrict access to pages such as Register, Index, Lostpassword.. ETC These are theoretical pages; as the OP has not specifically stated what kind of pages are being restricted

Comment: My first page is also my log on page index.php. When they log in it takes them to loggedin.php. If they go back to index.php I do indeed want the facebook effect so the index.php recognises they are already logged in and redirects them to logged in.php. Does that make more sense?

Comment: That's the same thing? He said if they are logged in they should be redirected.

Comment: @user1325308 , in that case. Use the 2nd code snippet in my answer at the top of your index.php file. And make sure you fix the path of the logged in file.

Comment: TJohnW That is spot on. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up two paths on your navigation menu like so:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
?>
<a href="loggedinpage.php">PageName</a>
<?php
}
elseif (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
?>
 <a href="login.php">Login</a>
 <a href="bla.php">Page</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

So depending whether the $_SESSION[] is set or not.. Different anchors will be displayed.

**Responding to comment**

Try creating an array with the restricted files.. Example:

```
if (isset($_SESSION))
{
   $Restrictions = array ("login.php", "index.php", "register.php");
  if (in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $Restrictions ))
  {
    die ("You Must Login To View These Pages!"); //I use die and an include in my scripts, but this will be called when the user is navigating to a page such as login.php when they already have an active session
  } 
}
```

What the above will do, will utilize the $_SERVER Array for the requested URL, if the users session is active and the user tries to navigate to said filed in the array, they will be presented with a `die` message. Ofcourse this can be changed to suit your needs.. and you can also do something similar using the same chunk, by restricting the users who are not logged in; from viewing the pages which you are required to be logged in.

*For the re-direct*

on your index.php, you could have something like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION))
{
 header("Location: member_area.php");
 exit; // exit to stop the rest of your page (index.php for example) from processing.
}
```

This will re-direct the user to a page, if they have an active session.

---

Looking at your question; you want the user to be re-directed to a member_area if `$_SESSION` is active.. Then use the last chunk under the name of "*For the re-direct*

Comment: But the problem with that is that the page is still loaded, I think the question was how to stop them from accessing a page. (In this case its when they manually type the login page.)

Comment: Try creating an array with the restrictions.. See my update in a minute.

Comment: That's correct. Like Facebook and Twitter. If you are logged in and go to Facebook.com you don't see the log in page but it redirects to your 'members area'

Comment: See my update ,is this something you are looking for? I have the exact implement on my software, it works; you may have to tweak your requirements.. But I can tell you, by using this exact chunk; it restricts the viewing

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you have above is roughly what you want.  It presumes that your login script writes a session value for `username`.  If you're unsure, or want to check, and since you say you're new, it might be helpful for you to take  a look at what session variables are set.  Just put this right below your `session_start()` line:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
exit;
```

Make sure you only use this for dev and comment it out when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your Logout.php script should look something like this.
$session_variable = $_SESSION['variable'];
session_unset($session_variable);
session_destroy();
header('Location: blah.php');

//Your session check script should look something like this. 
$session_variable = $_SESSION['variable'];
if(!isset($session_variable)) {
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: blah.php');
}
```

Comment: Note: You would probably want to add a few more check downs to the session check like whether or not the session userid matches up with the userid in the database etc -- but I think the point is there...

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `header("Location: http://www.site.com")` if there is something written before that. 
PHP header function has to be like this

```
<?php header("Location: http://www.site.com") ?>
```